# Please help me with this carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all here’s a codepen example https://codepen.io/CodingGilbert/pen/xJGvQB?editors=1010

To see what the current issue is, notice that there are 5 clothing-items, there are 2 items with the attribute of sale, if you click on sale in the navigation on the left side, you will see those 2 items showing in a new section. Within that section (sale), if you click the quickview button on the first item the popup will show up, but if you click the next button, you will see an item that does not belong in that section (linen-top item). This is happening because in the main section this item is between the 2 items with the sale attribute.

I believe this example is enough to illustrate the problem, this is happening in all sections. I do have an idea of why this is happening but I can’t see how to solve this… Below the JS code.

```
var data = [
  {
    product: "Haori Jacket",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Jacket",
    price: "$210.00",
    outwear: ""
  },
  {
    product: "Swing Dress",
    url: "swingdress.html",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d5226e4b0e3eb29871ecf/1443713579307/lauren-winter-swing-dress_0183.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Dress",
    price: "$218.00",
    dress: ""
  },
{
    product: "Jane Skirt",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d8fe4b0f1182e35da9a/1443712404868/kimem-long-pleated-skirt-black_0354.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Shirt",
    price: "$150.00",
    sale: "$263.00",
    bottom: ""
  },
  {
    product: "Linen Top",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d542ae4b088b5adb66691/1443714094740/ulihu-blue-linen-crop-top_0320.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Jacket",
    price: "$125.00",
    outwear: ""
  },
  {
    product: "Romy Top",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4e8be4b08ac15504170b/1443712656147/kimem-romy-dolman-top_0146.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Blouse",
    price: "$199.00",
    sale: "$300.00",
    top: ""
  }
];

// Generate template literal
function clothingView(item, index) {
  return (`
    <a href="${item.url}" class="shop-item">
    ${item.sale ? `<span class="shop-item__sale">Sale</span>`: ''}
      <img src=${item.image} alt="${item.altDesc}" class="shop-item__img">
      <div class="quickview">
        <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
        <span class="quickview__info">${item.product}
          <br>
          <span class="quickview__price">${item.price}
            ${item.sale ? `<span class="quickview__price--sale">${item.sale}</span>`: ''}
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class="shop-item__index">${index}</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    `);
};

// Append template literal to html structure based on category
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  const viewItems = clothingView(data[i], i);

  $('.all-items').append(viewItems);
  if ('accessory' in data[i]) { $('.accesories').append(viewItems); }
  if ('sale' in data[i]) { $('.sale').append(viewItems); }
};

// Change clothing-item popup img and info
function swapPopup(clothing) {
  $('#clothingImg').prop('src', clothing.image)
  $('#clothingName').text(clothing.product)
  $('#clothingPrice').text(clothing.price)
  clothing.sale ? $('#clothingSale').text(clothing.sale) : $('#clothingSale').text(null)
};

// Open popup window by clicking quickview btn
var currentPopup = 0;
$('.quickview__icon').click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.overlay').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});

  currentPopup = $(e.target).parent().children('.shop-item__index').text();
  swapPopup(data[currentPopup]);
});

// Popup prev and next buttons functionality
$('#popupPrev, #popupNext').click(function() {
  var end = data.length - 1;
  var direction = $(this).attr('id') === 'popupPrev' ? -1 : 1;
  currentPopup = Number(currentPopup) + direction;
  currentPopup = currentPopup < 0 ? end : currentPopup > end ? 0 : currentPopup;
  swapPopup(data[currentPopup]);
});

// Close popup window
  $('#closeIcon').click(function() {
  $('.overlay').css({
    'opacity': '0', 
    'visibility': 'hidden'});
  });

//Show clothing items by clicking nav categories
  $('.categories__link').click(function(){

    function showingSection(e) {
      $(e).fadeIn('slow');
      $(e).css('display', 'flex');
    };

    $('.products').css('display', 'none');
    showingSection('.' + this.id);
  });

// Hide sale icon on clothing-item hovering
  $('.shop-item').hover(
    function() { // Mouse in
    $('.shop-item__sale', this).fadeOut();
    },
    function() { // Mouse out
    $('.shop-item__sale', this).fadeIn();
    }
  );
```

Comment: it seems like the way your data is setup makes this problem much more difficult, would you be open to changing your data structure? for example, instead of having a key "top" as the category, just have each obj have a "category" key with a value of the category like `{ ... category: "top" }`

Comment: Of course! I know that the way I coded this wasn't probably the best way to do it, but that was the only way I could do it. I will change anything as long as can get this done!

Comment: @AndrewLohr, I already changed the data structure in the code pen.

Comment: You'll need some way to keep track of the current selected category (from the side menu). Maybe add a `selectedCat` class to the selected span. That way you can see which category is selected by querying the `selectedCat` class and using the `id`. Then in the quick view function you need to query the selected category and make sure only that category is shown in the next/prev slides (skip all ones that are not the selected category)

Answer (score 1):

You almost reach to the solution.
In this case, you can use grep or filter.
I think you should prepare 'filteredData' when you click the categories.

```
var filteredData = $.grep(data,
    function(record) {
        // if it has a sale column
        return (record.sale);
        // specific category
        // return (record.category === 'xxx');
    }
);
```

Maybe there is other ways, but the purpose is the same, you need to narrow down the data.

[UPDATED]
more detail.
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/91347wfd/)

[UPDATED2]
Ok, I see your all code now.
It seems that you need to some work. I show you an example, so you can pick up of necessary parts if you like. [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxzpZZ)

In the init process, you inserted all of products, so I followed that way.

Init process : data insert (all)

Change the categories : show / hide

After all, filtering data is only for the quick view, but I think it's ok unless the number of products is so huge.
(If you don't like it, you need to implements getting to the next/prev index from the data)

Comment: Let me see if I get this right, this function is going to triggered when I click in one of the navigation buttons to show a different sectio?, also is record the name of the array of objects? I am not sure what record would be here

Comment: I updated my post for you. $.grep is a kind of useful method by jQuery. This is like a for loop. The function is called for the number of data, so record means one data, if it's first, then record is data[0].

Comment: I noticed that there's an empty array called formatedData, but I don't see that you are using it anywhere in your code

Comment: Also it seems The $.grep function is not filtering the data, but the for loop is doing it right.

Comment: Sorry, speaking of formatedData, it was my mistake, but the $.grep is fine. Why do you think so? I updated the 'jsfiddle link' to show the result.

Comment: I intentionally didn't use your codepen, because I thought you could handle it. However, if it's too much for you, let me know.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for taking the time to help me with this, I really appreciated. I took a quick view at your code and it looks like it's working. I've been doing some changes to my code but your code definitely is going to be helpful! If I have questions about it I'll comeback here, hope you don't mind.